# Pygame MOUSEDOWN wont stop registering

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame, mouseevent

I am trying to run an event, where clicking a button replaces an image. I have tried it two ways.

1. mouse.get_pressed(). **Issue:** Once I release the mouse, the image
   disappears. I feel like this would be an easier approach, but I'm new to pygame and don't know how to do it.
2. MOUSEBUTTONDOWN. **Issue:** When I hit play, it infinitely runs the MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event. I know this because I put a print statement after, and it just nonstop prints in the terminal. 
   Here's my code. If you need to see more, please let me know, thanks!

```
def replace(x, y):
    transparent = (0,0,0,0)
    replaceImg = pygame.image.load("tree.png")
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if click[0] == 1:
        level1Img.fill(transparent)
        screen.blit(replaceImg, (x, y))
```

```
running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((100,150,180))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    draw_level(level1X, level1Y)
    draw_level2(level2X, level2Y)
    draw_button("Complete", 355, 550, 90, 30, green, bright_green)

    for i in range(num_trees):
        draw_trees(tree_leftX[i], tree_leftY[i], i)
        draw_trees(tree_rightX[i], tree_rightY[i], i)

    # Lines between levels
    pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (level1X + 32,level1Y), (level2X + 32,level2Y + 64), 5)

    replace(level1X, level1Y)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Here is a picture of it, basically I want the "complete" button to replace that bottom little pad icon.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` is not "the mouse button is currently down"; it's a constant value, that is to be compared with an input event's `type`.

What you want, instead, is `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`; this returns 3 values, those being primary mouse, secondary mouse, and middle mouse. Since you're only using primary mouse, you can ignore the latter two.

You're likely clearing the screen by some method in ....; also, you're running display.update() twice, once at the end of the MOUSEBUTTONDOWN if and again immediately after replace() returns. This might seem irrelevant, but it's always best to fix stuff like that in case it's somehow causing the issue.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the clarification! The image is still disappearing... I am going to add my while loop, do you mind taking a peek and seeing if you notice anything? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @putnam your test:

```
if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
```

is always going to be true because it is just looking at the value of `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` which is a constant defined by pygame.

if you want to use an approach that looks for mouse events, then inside your main game loop you need an event loop and to check the events returned for the event types you want to react to. Like this:

```
    while running:
        ...
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            ...
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                do_stuff_when_mouse_button_gets_pressed()
                ...
```

Note that this is checking if any of the `event`s returned from the `event.get()` have their `type` attribute equal to the defined pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN constant.

This approach does require code structure where things get called from the event loop rather than the mouse buttons being examined for their state in the middle of some other block of code.

Comment: Thank you! I saw that the value of pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN is 5. Will I need that value for this approach at all?

Comment: Also, I have been messing around with `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, and it is super inconsistent in when it registers clicks.. I saw a different post on that issue, but if you have a solid idea of why, I'd love to hear it too!

Comment: You don't need the exact value, it's just an identifier--if you're using a process_input function, it'll expect an `event`, which will have a `type`. If the type is 5--that is to say, `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`--then you know the event will be for a mouse click.